# How do I clear previous calculated data if user asks to repeat program? C++

Tags: c++, c++11

Hello so I am a new programming student and I am practicing for my final. I know my program has flaws, but the major flaw is when the user repeats the program the new calculations are added onto the previous ones. How would I correct it?
My code is below for this task:

```
// Andranik Keshishyan, Quiz 2
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip> //For setw and other formatting
#include <ctime> //For random number generation
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    bool repeat = true; //Repeats program if true
    srand(time(0)); //Random number generation
    double amount_thrown, dice1, dice2, sum1, sum2, sum3, sum4, avg1, avg2, avg3; //Variables
    char space = ' '; //Space for Formatting

    cout <<"This program will roll 2 dice and calculate their sum and average depending on the amount of throws\n";
    cout <<"The amount of throws cannot exceed 12\n";

    while (repeat){ //Will repeat program if true.

        cout <<"How many times would you like the dice thrown?: ";
        cin >> amount_thrown;

        cout << "\n";

        if ((amount_thrown < 1 || amount_thrown > 12)||(!(cin>>amount_thrown))){ //Checks to see if user input is valid.
            cout <<"This is an invalid input of dice throws.\n";
        }
        else //Continues program if valid.
        {
            cout <<"Throw" << setw(3) << space <<"Die 1" << setw(3) << space << "Die 2" << setw(3) << space << "Sum\n";

            for(int x=1; x<=amount_thrown; x++){ //Loops program until amount of throws equals to user input

                dice1 = rand() % 6 + 1;
                dice2 = rand() % 6 + 1;
                sum1 = dice1+dice2; //Calculates sum of dice1 + dice 2
                sum2 += dice1; //Calculates sum of all dice 1 throws
                sum3 += dice2; // Calcules sum of all dice 2 throws
                sum4 += sum1; // Calculates summ of the sum
                avg1 = sum2/2; // Calculates avg of sum of dice 1 throws
                avg2 = sum3/2; // Calculates avg of sum of dice 2 throws
                avg3 = sum4/2; // Calculates ave of sum of dice 1 + dice 2

                cout << setw(2) << x << setw(7) << dice1 << setw(8) << dice2 << setw(9) << sum1 << endl;

            }

            cout << "-------------------------------------\n";
            cout << "Sum" << setw(5) << space << sum2 << setw(6) << space << sum3 << setw(6) << space << sum4 << endl;
            cout << "Avg" << setw(5) << space << avg1 << setw(5) << space << avg2 << setw(5) << space << avg3 << endl;


        }

        cout << "\nWould you like to roll the dice again?[y=repeat / anything else=stop]: ";
        char answer;
        cin >> answer;
        cin.ignore(1000, '\n'); //Makes sure other inputs are ignored
        answer=tolower(answer);
        repeat = answer == 'y'; //Program will repeat if user inputs true char y. 

    }
    cout << "Thank you, goodbye" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question, and provide [mcve] in the question itself, and not in 3rd party links.

Comment: `if ((amount_thrown < 1 || amount_thrown > 12)||(!(cin>>amount_thrown)))`: That's going to read in the `amount_thrown` a second time. `for(int x=1; x<=amount_thrown; x++)`: zero-based loops are idiomatic. `avg1 = sum2/2;`: That's only the average of the last two dice thrown, not of all `amount_thrown` times. Also, you should use more descriptive variable names.

Answer (score 2):

You are not resetting your `sum2`, `sum3`, and `sum4` variables back to 0 on each iteration of the `while` loop.  That is why their values are cumulative over repeats of the program.

In fact, you are not even initializing them at all, so the total sum will be random garbage anyway.

You need to reset them to 0 on each `while` iteration, before entering the `for` loop.

Comment: Thank you so much for the pointers! I just added the (!(cin>>amount_thrown)). I'm sure it seems ridiculous but again I am learning and experimenting. My professor has told me to use better variable names. Would you give me an example of what you would have named some of my variables?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to place all code in a function like `void userInput();` then in `int main()` have a `while` loop which calls `userInput();` then `system("CLR");` which allows you to reset.